# How can I add redis keys to another instance

Tags: python, redis

I'm trying to move existing keys from a Redis instance (A) to another instance (B) without loosing B's keys.
Is there any tool I can use or should I write the code by myself?

Comment: I do not understand why you will loose B's keys if you move keys from A to B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to official Redis cluster tutorial: "... however currently there is no way for redis-trib to automatically rebalance the cluster checking the distribution of keys across the cluster nodes and intelligently moving slots as needed. This feature will be added in the future."

So you need to write the code yourself to distribute the keys to Redis instances.  If you want to migrate one or more keys from one node to another, you must migrate first the hashslots and then the actual keys otherwise an error occurred.

In general, you need a code procedure that executes these Ruby lines of code (prototype in redis-trib.rb):

Code to migrate the slot from source to target node

```
target.r.cluster("setslot",slot,"importing",source.info[:name])
source.r.cluster("setslot",slot,"migrating",target.info[:name])
```

Code to migrate the actual key

```
source.r.client.call(["migrate",target.info[:host],target.info[:port],$keys_of_source[i],0,15000]).
```

You can use existing code for the migration from here: https://github.com/projecteru/redis-trib.py

You can use these lines of code:

```
def migrate_slots_stable(src_host, src_port, dst_host, dst_port, slots):

    if src_host == dst_host and src_port == dst_port:
        raise ValueError('The source and the target node are the same.  A good reason is that the key is stored already on target node!')
    with Connection( src_host, src_port ) as t:
        nodes, myself = _list_masters( t, src_host)
    slots = set( slots )
    print('\x1b[6;30;42m' + '*****************************************MIGRATION PROCEDURE******************************************' + '\x1b[0m')
    print('\x1b[6;30;42m' + '******************************************************************************************************' + '\x1b[0m')
    print '* Migrating slots: ', slots , "* \n"
    for n in nodes:
        if n.host == dst_host and n.port == dst_port:
            return _migr_slots_stable( myself, n, slots, nodes )
    #raise ValueError( 'Two nodes are not in the same cluster' )


def _migr_slots_stable(source_node, target_node, slots, nodes):
    key_count = 0
    for slot in slots:
        key_count += _migr_one_slot_stable(source_node, target_node, slot, nodes)
        _migr_one_slot_stable( source_node, target_node, slot, nodes )
        #print "* keys_count that exists in these slot(s): ", key_count,' *'
        #print "\n"
        #print '* Migrated succesfully:',len(slots),'slot(s) and ',key_count,'key(s) from SOURCE NODE --> node_id:',source_node.node_id,'host:',source_node.host,'port:',source_node.port,'to TARGET NODE --> node_id:', target_node.node_id,'host:',target_node.host,'port:',target_node.port,' *'
    #print('\x1b[6;30;42m' + '******************************************************************************************************' + '\x1b[0m')
    print "\n"


def _migr_one_slot_stable(source_node, target_node, slot, nodes):
    def expect_exec_ok(m, conn, slot):
        if m.lower() != 'ok':
            conn.raise_('\n'.join([
            'Error while moving slot [ %d ] between' % slot,
            'Source node - %s:%d' % (source_node.host, source_node.port),
            'Target node - %s:%d' % (target_node.host, target_node.port),
            'Got %s' % m]))

    # Set the new node as the owner of the slot in all the known nodes
    # Bind the hash slot to a different node
    @retry(stop_max_attempt_number=16, wait_fixed=100)
    def setslot_stable(conn, slot, node_id):
        m = conn.execute('cluster', 'setslot', slot, 'node', node_id)
        expect_exec_ok(m, conn, slot)

    source_conn = source_node.get_conn()
    target_conn = target_node.get_conn()

    # Same in Ruby with these lines of code
    # the target node importing the slot and the source node migrating it
    try:
        expect_exec_ok(
        target_conn.execute('cluster', 'setslot', slot, 'importing',
                            source_node.node_id),
        target_conn, slot)
    except hiredis.ReplyError, e:
        if 'already the owner of' not in e.message:
        target_conn.raise_(e.message)

    try:
        expect_exec_ok(
        source_conn.execute('cluster', 'setslot', slot, 'migrating',
                            target_node.node_id),
        source_conn, slot)
    except hiredis.ReplyError, e:
        if 'not the owner of' not in e.message:
        source_conn.raise_(e.message)


    keys = _migr_keys_stable(source_conn, target_node.host, target_node.port, slot)
    setslot_stable(source_conn, slot, target_node.node_id)
    for node in nodes:
        setslot_stable(node.get_conn(), slot, target_node.node_id)
    return keys

def _migr_keys_stable(src_conn, target_host, target_port, slot):
    key_count = 0
    while True:
        keys = src_conn.execute('cluster', 'getkeysinslot', slot, 10)
        if len(keys) == 0:
            return key_count
        key_count += len(keys)
        src_conn.execute_bulk(
        # Same in Ruby with this line of code:    source.r.client.call(["migrate",target.info[:host],target.info[:port],$keys_of_source[i],0,15000])
        [['migrate', target_host, target_port, k, 0, 30000] for k in keys])
```

The first function that triggered is `def migrate_slots_stable` and has parameters the source host, the source port, the destination host, the destination port and a set of the hashslot that you want to transfer.